# C++ Close a process without a window correctly

Tags: c++, windows, process

I've got a service which should close a background process. The problem is that the background process has to free some ressources first before it gets terminated. If that process had a window, I could use SendMessage to send WM_QUIT, WM_CLOSE,... to the window but it does not have a window. 
I've also found the SetConsoleCtrlHandler function but I still dont't know how to shutdown the process. If I terminate it, the ConsoleHandler won't be called anyway. How can I close a process without terminating it. Is there any possiblity to send a WM_QUIT Message to a process without a window handle?

Comment: You'll need to change the "background process" so it can receive a signal from outside of the process.  Anything goes, but a global named event created with CreateEvent() can certainly do that job.

Comment: thats a nice approach. Creating global events is completely new for me. Anyway. I've implemented the global event and it works. The only problem is that I use hooks in the process. And the call to WaitForSingleObject slows down the whole process for about 6-7 seconds. I am using LowlevelMouseHooks what means that the user can't use his mouse for a few seconds. Do you have any idea how to solve that problem? @HansPassant

Comment: Execute WaitForSingleObject in another thread